# How to I alter Vue component on firebase auth change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lifecycle

I have a part of my Vue navbar that has a Login or Logout button. I want it to change depending on whether firebase user is logged in or not.

It does work but only when I refresh the page after logging in. I tried putting the .onAuthStateChanged() in an updated() life cycle hook but I still have the same problem.

How do I make this work?

```
    <div>
      <span v-if="loggedIn">
        <router-link to="/logout">
          <v-btn depressed v-on:click="pressed">Logout</v-btn>
        </router-link>
       </span>
       <span v-else>
         <router-link to="/login">
           <v-btn depressed>Login</v-btn>
          </router-link>
        </span>
     </div>


export default {
 mounted() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=> {
        if(user){
            this.loggedIn = true;
        } else {
            this.loggedIn = false;
        }
    })
 },
```

Comment: try with putting loggedIn  as computed property

Comment: Where do you define `loggedIn`?

Comment: It's defined in the data(){return{loggedIn: false}} in the next block of code.